# Using one HOC for multiple Components (ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs, class, components

I want to use "useParams" and "useNavigate" but my components are class component and I can't use "useParams" and "useNavigate". so I had to make **HOC** to access them. but ***I can't use a single HOC for two or three components at the same time***.
this is my HOC (**withRouter**):

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const withRouter = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <WrappedComponent {...props} params={params} navigate={navigate} />;
};
```

in my **showMovie** an **movieForm** I exported them like below:

```
 export default withRouter(ShowMovie);
```

and

```
 export default withRouter(MovieForm);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what do you mean by *but I can't use a single HOC for two or three components at the same time.* ?

Comment: For example i can use my HOC for my showMovie component or movieForm. I can't use HOC for both of them at the same time. I keep getting error for getting data from my movieForm component after i use HOC for both of them. But when i use HOC for one at a time the components work perfectly.